# Jquery Lightbox cant exit from the lightbox

Tags: jquery, wordpress, lightbox

I have used these codes and set it up on worddpress

http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/build-lightbox-responsive-html5-touch-interface

to get a lightbox effect for my images. The next,previous buttons dont function and neither

can I exit from the lightbox pops up

Comment: Is the original demo working? Then you have an error in your code. Please post it as fiddle.

Comment: Wat is a fiddle? Original is working. Im not able to make it work on wordpress